# Well-foundedness of divisibility vs well-foundedness of right- and left-divisibility

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Say that a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) (i.e., a reflexive and transitive binary relation) $\preceq$ on a set $X$ is

- *artinian* if there is no sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ of elements of $X$ with $x_{n+1} \prec x_n$ for each $n$, where $u \prec v$ means as usual that $u \preceq v$ and $v \not\preceq u$ (some authors prefer the term "well-founded", others the term "noetherian"; I'm going for the term "artinian" because it sounds natural in the light of certain applications);
- *noetherian* if its [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(order_theory)) $\preceq^{\rm op}$ is artinian, where $x \preceq^{\rm op} y$ iff $y \preceq x$.

Next, let $H$ be a (commutative or non-commutative) monoid and denote

- by $\mid_H$ the *divisibility preorder* (on $H$), defined by $x \mid_H y$ iff $y = uxv$ for some $u, v \in H$;
- by $\dashv_H$ the "divides-from-the-right'' preorder, defined by $x \dashv_H y$ iff $y = ux$ for some $u \in H$;
- by $\vdash_H$ the "divides-from-the-left" preorder, that is, the "divides-from-the-right" preorder in the opposite monoid $H^{\rm op}$ of $H$.

My question is **whether $\mid_H$ is artinian iff both $\dashv_H$ and $\vdash_H$ are artinian**. I'm sure this is well known, but I haven't been able so far to **find a reference**. (By the way, is there a more standard (relational) symbol for the preorders I'm denoting by $\dashv_H$ and $\vdash_H$?)

The duals of these preorders were thoroughly studied in

> J.A. Green, *On the Structure  of Semigroups*, Annals of Math. **54** (1951) 163-172;

whence they are often referred to as the *Green preorders*. In particular, Theorem 4 in Green's paper implies that, if both $\dashv_H$ and $\vdash_H$ are <strike>artinian</strike> noetherian, then so also is $\mid_H$ (thanks to Benjamin Steinberg who made me notice in the comments below that I had misread Green's definitions and hence the conclusions of the theorem).

For the record, what I can prove is that the following are equivalent:

1. $H$ is *acyclic* (i.e., $uxv \ne x$ for all $u, v, x \in H$ with $u \notin H^\times$ or $v \notin H^\times$) and $\mid_H$ is artinian.
2. $H$ is *unit-cancellative* (i.e., $xy \ne x$ and $x \ne yx$ for all $x, y \in H$ with $y \notin H^\times$) and both $\dashv_H$ and $\vdash_H$ are artinian.

Here, $H^\times$ is the group of units of the monoid $H$.

Comment: The standard notation for these preorders uses the reverse conventions.  We write in semigroup theory $s\leq_{\mathcal J} t$ if $s=utv$, we write $s\leq_{\mathcal R} t$ if $s=tu$ and $s\leq_{\mathcal L} t$ if $s=ut$.  For us riight versus left has to do with left ideal versus right ideal rather than left/divisibility versus right divisiblity.

Comment: Also, I suspect.Green is using the conventions that I am which means maybe the his mnimum condition is your maximum?

Comment: Green’s minimum condition is different than what you are considering.  He is considering the minimum condition on principal left/right/two-sided ideals and you are considering the reverse orders.

Comment: You are look at noetherian rather than artinian from the semigroup view point.

Comment: If you consider the bicyclic monoid with presentation $\langle a,b\mid ab=1\rangle$ there is only one principal two-sided ideal but you have infinite descending chains of principal right or left ideals and this is probably what Green is referring to. But these infinite chains got opposite the way you want and there are no infinite chains in the opposite direction in this example

Comment: If you look at Baer-Levi semigroups they are simple on one-side (so have only one class on the two-sided and one of the one sided classes, but I think they have infinite chains on the other side but I have to think which way the chains go.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks a lot. I think you're right and I messed up with up and down while reading through Green's paper. I'll re-check everything with a fresher mind and edit my post accordingly. Luckily enough, the equivalence between 1. and 2. in the OP is not affected by my misunderstanding of Green's definitions (the proof of the equivalence doesn't depend on Green's result, which I learned about only a few days ago).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give a semigroup example.  You can adjoin an identity to get a monoid example.

I think your question (and also what Green had in mind, which is something different) is answered by Baer-Levi semigroups.  Let $X$ be a countably infinite set and let $S$ be the semigroup of all one-to-one maps $f\colon X\to X$ with $X\setminus f(X)$ infinite.  This is a left cancellative and left simple semigroup with no idempotents.  A proof can be found in Clifford and Preston, Algebraic Theory of Semigroups, Volume 2 in Theorem 8.2, except they follow the convention of writing $xf$ instead of $f(x)$ and using right actions and hence say right simple and right cancellative.

So it follows that for any $f,g\in S$, there is $h\in S$ with $hf=g$ and so there is one right divisibility class and one two-sided divisibility class (or in semigroup parlance one $\mathcal L$-class and one $\mathcal J$-class).  I claim there are infinite chains in both direction for the $\mathcal R$-order (what you call left divisibility).  I have to confess I can never read papers talking about left and right divisibility because they are both switching left and right and also up and down with respect to the way I think.

**Edit.**  Since the proof is short, I am adding a proof that $S$ is left simple.  If $f,g\colon X\to X$ are injective with $X\setminus f(X)$ and $X\setminus g(X)$ infinite,  choose an infinite subset $Y$ of $X\setminus g(X)$ with $(X\setminus g(X))\setminus Y$ infinite.  Define $h\colon X\to X$ by $h(f(x)) =g(x)$ and defining $h$ on $X\setminus f(X)$ to be some arbitrary bijection between $X\setminus f(X)$ and $Y$.  Then $hf=g$, $h$ is injective and $h\in S$ since $h(X) = g(X)\cup Y$ and so $X\setminus h(X) = (X\setminus g(X))\setminus Y$, which is infinite.

I claim that if $f,g\in S$, then $f=gh$ for some $h$ if and only if the range of $f$ is contained in the range of $g$ and $X\setminus g^{-1}(f(X))$ is infinite.

Obviously, if $f=gh$ with $h$ any function, then $f(X)\subseteq g(X)$ and since $g$ is one-to-one we must have $h=g^{-1}\circ f$ (which makes sense since $f(X)\subseteq g(X)$).  For this to belong to $S$, we need $X\setminus g^{-1}(f(X))$ to be infinite.

To get an infinite descending chain of right ideals is now easy (and this is what Green was likely thinking of).  One always has $fS\supsetneq f^2S\supsetneq\cdots$ since by left cancellativity, if $f^n=f^{n+1}g$, then since $f$ is injective $fg=1_X$, which contradicts $X\setminus f(X)$ being infinite. So this does left divisibility is not noetherian.

To go the other way, let $X$ be countably infinite and $f\colon X\to X$ any element of $S$.  Let $Z$ be an infinite subset of $X\setminus f(X)$ with $X\setminus (f(X)\cup Z)$ is infinite.  Now we can choose a partition of $X$ into two infinite sets $X_1,X_2$ and have $g$ send $X_1$ bijectively to $f(X)$ and send $X_2$ bijectively to $Z$.  Then $fS\subsetneq gS$ by the criterion above and so we can build an infinite ascending chain as well by continuing this process.  So left divisibility is not artinian.

Comment: If I understand the *idea* correctly, you consider a monoid $H$ with the property that (i) every element is left-invertible and (ii) the ACC on principal right ideals is not satisfied: In the parlance of the OP, it follows from (i) that the divisibility preorder is artinian (equivalently, $H$ satisfies the ACC on principal ideals), and so also is the divides-from-the-right preorder (equivalently, $H$ satisfies the ACC on principal left ideals); while (ii) means that the divides-from-the-left preorder is not artinian. Nice!

Comment: It's not a monoid.  It's a semigroup.  All elements right  divide each other but it has infinite ascending and descending chains from any element for left divisibility.  If you adjoin an identity you get a monoid with 2 right divisibility classes

Comment: But you don't have left invertibility of any non unit.

Comment: Whoops! Somehow, I had mindlessly translated the condition "for fixed $a$ and $b$, the equation $xa = b$ has at least one solution" to "$x = ba'$ with $a'$ a left inverse of $a$".

Comment: The point is that the equation has a solution for nonidenity elements. You can't solve ab=1. If every element was left invertibile you would have a group.

Comment: Many thanks (also for the patience)! I think what I had in mind might be the following: Your  is the unitization of a certain right ideal  of a suitable monoid . While the elements of  are not left-invertible in , they are so in . This and  being a right ideal of  guarantee that, for all ,∈, the equ = is solvable in  (whence ACCP, ACCPL and their DCC duals hold). And now the particular choice you make on  (the transformation monoid of an infinite set ) and  (the non-invertible injects : → s.t.  ∖ () is infinite) prevents ACCPR & DCCPR.

Comment: In the transformation monoid K, Green's relations are different.  The monoid K doesn't have any chain conditions on left ideals.  H does since you are Just adding a maximum to all your posets.